# How to set the server name as a global variable in javascript from an xml file?

Tags: javascript, xml, configuration

I have a web application which makes some Ajax calls and I want to set the server domain name to be used for the ajax calls in an XML configurations file. I have seen [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) which shows how to parse xml file in javascript. But the problem is that I need to make an Ajax call to parse the xml file and for that I need to know the server domain name (which I am already trying to fetch from the xml).

So how can I set the server name in an XML file and use to make ajax calls? Is there any other way I can configure the server name outside the javascript file itself?

---

EDIT:

Can I do something like this (in which I would not need to set the server name at all and wont need config file) :

```
 function getMetricNotifications()
{    
 var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/rest/general/notifications/metrics",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    return response;
}
```

Without mentioning the domain name `localhost:8080` (locally) or `http://mysite.com:8080` (on server) at the beginning of the URL in 
`xmlhttp.open("GET","/rest/general/notifications/metrics",true);`

I tried it and I got : `uncaught syntaxerror unexpected end of input` before the last line. Any thoughts?

---

2nd EDIT:

```
function getMetricNotifications(){   
 var xmlhttp;
 var response = '';
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
             response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
             return response;
          }
      };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/rest/general/notifications/metrics",true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Now I'm calling this function and printing the result and it prints "undefined", although accessing the rest resource directly in the browser gives the correct JSON response.
Why it is not getting the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which backend technology do you run on. You need to parse the XML file on the server side and insert the server name in its output.

In PHP, you could do something like

```
<html>
<head><!-- rest of head -->
<script>
<?php $xml = simplexml_load_file('cfg.xml'); ?>
var server_name = <?= json_encode($xml->servername) ?>
</script>
```

Then you could user `server_name` in your JavaScript code.

### Ad the EDIT:

Yes, this is the preferred URL format in most cases.

The error you are seeing is probably caused by a malformed/incomplete JSON input.

The request you are performing is asynchronous so you need to wait for the data to be available/downloaded. The `xhr.responseText` is empty right after the `xhr.send()` call. Wait for the request to get to the ready state of 4 (complete).

```
// ...
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    // ... do something with data ...
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

### Ad the second EDIT:

I suppose you use the function in a synchronous manner such as

```
var data = getMetricNotifications();
```

You cannot do that if you're getting the data asynchronously. You need to get familiar with the concept of callback functions and do this instead:

```
getMetricNotifications(function (data) {
  // work with the received data
});
```

Instead of returning the data, you pass it to the callback function like this:

```
var getMetricNotifications = function (callback) {
  // ... do the call ...
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && ...) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      callback(data);
    }
  };
  // ... 
};
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, what is the difference between the second and third pieces of code? Is callback a reserved word or I need to define it somewhere else?

Comment: I have two functions: `get` doing the ajax call and the `load` calls the first and uses the returned data. The `load` is called on a specific button click event... I used your second piece of code `getMetricNotifications(function (data) ... ` but it is not recognized as a function, how can I call it?

Comment: `callback` is the name of the argument of `getMetricNotifications` ;)